# $f(x,y)=x^2-xy+4y^2$ and the ellipse $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2+4y^2<1 \} $

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)=x^2-xy+4y^2$ and the ellipse $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2+4y^2<1 \} $.

Hey,

I already calculated the maxima/minima of $f$ which is just a global minimum in $(0,0)$ on $E$ and also the maxima/minima on the boundary of $E$ in terms of $f$.

The points that I found for the boundary are:

Minimum: $(0.5\sqrt2,0.25\sqrt2$ and $(-(\sqrt2)^{-1},(-2\sqrt2)^{-1})$
Maximum: $((-\sqrt2)^{-1},(2\sqrt2)^{-1})$ and $((\sqrt2)^{-1},(2\sqrt2)^{-1})$

Now I need to show if the maxima/minima that I found for the boundary of $E$ are maxima/minima of the set E* which contains E and its boundary.

My idea was to look at the partial derivate of f in a close neighborhood which is contained in E. For instance I showed that $(-(\sqrt2)^{-1},(-2\sqrt2)^{-1})$ cannot be a local minimum for f on E* because the partial derivative at this point in positive x-direction is negative, so the function is decreasing on a neighborhood contained in E.
I applied the same on $((\sqrt2)^{-1},(2\sqrt2)^{-1})$ and showed that this cannot be a local maximum for f on E*.

I hope you know what I mean. My question is: Am I even right? For me this makes sense, but I don't know

And the second thing is:
I tried to show what's going with $((-\sqrt2)^{-1},(2\sqrt2)^{-1})$. But that's no that easy because partial derivatives are ok. So I figured out a general term (with the limit definition of directional derivative with a general vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ with $v_1>0$ and $v_2<0$ to make sure that the vector is still in E* and it also came out that $((-\sqrt2)^{-1},(2\sqrt2)^{-1})$ cannot be a local maximum of f with respect to E*. Bu that was really complicated.

I think the exercise doesn't force you to overcomplicate it like this.
Is there an easier way to show this? And am I even right?

I would be sooo pleased if some could help me :))

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that you haven't studied Lagrange multipliers yet.)  The function and the constraint ellipse both have symmetry about the origin, so we can expect that the extremal values on the boundary of the ellipse are found at points with coordinates $ \ (\pm x \ , \ \pm mx) \ $ and $ \ (\pm x \ , \ \mp nx) \ \ , $  with $ \ m \ , \ n  \ > \ 0 \ \ . $  At these points, the function has its maximal value, $ \ (1+n+4n^2)·x^2 \ , $ on the line $ \ y = -nx \ $ and its minimal value, $ \ (1-m+4m^2)·x^2 \ , $ on the line $ \ y = mx \ \ . $

The problem with looking only at the partial derivatives $ \ f_x = 2x - y \ $ and $ \ f_y = -x + 8y \ $ is that they are individually equal to zero along the lines $ \ y = 2x \ $ and $ \ y = \frac18 x \  \ , $ respectively.  But the points that you've located (which can be done, for instance, by inserting the constraint equation into the function expression to reduce that problem to finding the extrema of a single-variable function) do not lie on either line.  [In fact, the extrema are found on the lines $ \ y \ = \ \pm \frac12 x \ \ . $ ]

What will tell you that your point is at an extremum   is that the *gradient* of the function, $ \ \langle 2x - y \ , \ -x+8y \rangle \ \ , $ has the same slope as the normal to the constraint ellipse, $ \ m_N \ = \ \frac{4y}{x} \ \ .  $  (This is equivalent to saying that the level curve for the function is tangent to the constraint curve.)   For the point $ \ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \ , \ \frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \right) \ \ , $ we find
$$ m_N \ = \ \frac{4 \ · \ \frac{1}{2\sqrt2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}} \ = \ \frac{4 · \sqrt2}{2 · \sqrt2} \ = \ 2 \ \ \ \text{and} $$ $$ \langle 2x - y \ , \ -x+8y \rangle \ = \ \langle \frac{4 \ - \ 1}{2\sqrt2} \ , \ \frac{-2 \ + \ 8}{2\sqrt2} \rangle \ = \ \frac{3}{2 \sqrt2} · \langle 1 \ , \ 2 \rangle \ \ . $$

So the function gradient and ellipse normal slope match at that point, and similarly agree at the other three points you found.  They can be characterized as locations of function maxima or minima using the symmetry argument above or by direct comparison of the function values (which prove to be $ \ \frac54 \ $ and $ \ \frac34 \ \ , $ the level curves for which are shown in red in the graph below; the constraint ellipse is in blue, the lines $ \ y \ = \ \pm \frac12 x \   $ in green) .

[image]